# >UITableview crash (terminate called throwing an exception (lldb))

Tags: iphone, ios

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cellName=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell1"];
    NSDictionary *contentdict=[innerarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *cellidentify=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentify];

}
```

this my code every thing is working but the crash appears when i scroll the tableview 
even i have given the array value correctly and given the delegate and datasource as self 
is there any thing i need to write r change ?????
i am using Xcode 4.5

Comment: Is that seriously how the method looks like?!

Comment: Is the data being shown in the tableview ?

Comment: Can you put whole crash log ? Are you using ARC ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...may be it help....

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *contentdict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    if([innerarray count]>0)
    {
       contentdict =[innerarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

// Write your other cell stuff.... 

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's crashing because you are not returning any cells from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Change `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];


    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
    }

    //do something with the cell

   return cell;
}
```